# How to modify JSON Stringified form information on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi guys I am taking all form values on submit. Firstly I use

`var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());`

and the result gives me

```
[{"name":"deviceName","value":"Ball"},{"name":"deviceType","value":"4949"}]
```

but my json should be

```
{"deviceName":"Ball","deviceType":4949}
```

and also I should determine whether a value is string or int, while modifying json

Comment: The name value pairs are generated by  serializeArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do

```
var x = [{"name":"deviceName","value":"Ball"},{"name":"deviceType","value":"4949"}];
var y = {};
$.each(x,function(key,value){
    y[value['name']]= value['value'];
 });
console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
```

**NOTE:**
I have taken the variable names as `x` and `y`, but you can choose to have some meaningful variable names.

If you want to know the datatype of the value you can use `typeof` inside the `each` loop.

Look at the fiddle link [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04pf16ec/)